# Intellij idea 2021.2 cannot render markdown table currently?

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown

I use idea 2021.2 and corresponding markdown plugin. But the simple table cannot display in previous mode:

[image]

Why? I found somebody has related the problem to the JavaFx, however, I think it is occured in old version idea. I cannot find javafx render option in my version.

How to solve it?

Comment: Please always add the source code you are having a problem with. This will increase the chances of getting an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong **Markdown** syntax.

The following code works fine (minimum three `-` for table header)

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| :--- | :--- |
| AAA | BBB |
```